# Javascript: how do I insert the domain at the current position of the cursor?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Can Javascript in the form of a bookmarklet or similar, insert the domain of the current page at the position of the cursor? How?

Interested in inserting both `stackoverflow.com`, `www.stackoverflow.com` as well as just `www`.

(Use case: I am writing a question here at SO, the cursor is in either the title text field or the question body text area and I want to insert the domain name at the current position of the cursor).

Comment: It's a bit confusing. So assuming you're on `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065000/javascript-how-do-i-insert-the-domain-at-the-current-position-of-the-cursor`, when the bookmarklet is clicked, the text `stackoverflow.com` should be inserted where the cursor is?

Comment: Do you need it to work with `contentEditable` elements, or just textareas/text inputs? If there’s a non-empty selection, what should happen to it?

Comment: @Ry- Hmm, what's the use case for 'contentEditable` elements?

Comment: WYSIWYG editors. Unless SO is your actual use case.

Comment: @Ry- My usecase is mostly entering e-mailaddresses where I create a new address that contains the domain everytime I register a new account or similar. So I enter something like `d-b+`, click the bookmarklet and `stackoverflow.com` is inserted followed by me entering `@gmail.com`. End result is `d-b+stackoverflow.com@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When focusing the textarea, click the bookmarklet, and use `document.activeElement` to identify the textarea, and `.slice` its value, concatenating with `window.location.origin`:

```
javascript: (() => {
  const textarea = document.activeElement;
  const { selectionStart } = textarea;
  textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0, selectionStart) + window.location.origin + textarea.value.slice(selectionStart);
})();
```

If you want the bookmarklet to work for the iframe inside `https://robot-parts.confetti.events/`, then access the `contentWindow.document` to get to the `activeElement`:

```
javascript: (() => {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('.signup-iframe').contentWindow.document.activeElement;
  const { selectionStart } = textarea;
  textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0, selectionStart) + window.location.origin + textarea.value.slice(selectionStart);
})();
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't get your script to work fully. If I load https://robot-parts.confetti.events/ and click the RSVP button (Robot Parts), a box where you can enter your name etc appears. Also note that the URL changes, "/signup" is added at the end. Running this bookmarklet to insert the domain name here results in nothing. However, if I instead load https://robot-parts.confetti.events/signup (that is, the same address as you see after clicking the button in the first scenario) and then run the bookmarklet something is inserted. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's because, when navigating to `https://robot-parts.confetti.events/`, that area of the DOM is actually an *iframe*: `<iframe class="signup-iframe" src="/signup?preload=true"></iframe>`. When the focus is inside an iframe, there won't be a `document.activeElement`, because the iframe is a completely different execution context. In contrast, when you navigate to /signup` directly, you're no longer in an iframe, so `document.activeElement` works. As always, when debugging, you can often find the source of the error by opening the browser console and looking for error messages

Comment: Depends on the site's setup. If it's on the same domain, you can probably access the inner iframe and access the active element, but if it's on a different domain, cross-site restrictions will probably prevent it from working. For a comprehensive solution that works cross-origin, you'll probably need a userscript that runs on both pages, so that the parent page can send a message to the child page, and the child page can listen for a cross-origin `postMessage`. Kinda complicated.

Comment: It is on the same domain.

Comment: Then just access the inner document

Comment: How? I don't know that much Javascript.

Comment: Use the code in the answer. When you have a reference to an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain, reference its `contentWindow` to get a reference to the iframe's window, from which you can get the iframe's document.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to make it universal so it can be used in both situations?

Comment: For this particular site, perhaps, but a general solution would be pretty difficult unless you know in advance which iframes are in the page that would have a focused child input.

Comment: Where did you get `signup-iframe`from? Was that the `name` attribute of that iframe? They seem to have changed the structure of their site now, for a current example see https://ok2maj.confetti.events/signup

Comment: @d-b It no longer uses an embedded iframe, so the first code block in my answer looks to work fine

Answer (score 1):

This function adds an eventlistner for the keyboard shortcut `ctrl`+`g` and inserts the current url at the cursor position for input and textarea tags

```
const fields = ['INPUT','TEXTAREA'];
function doc_keyUp(e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 71) {
    // call your function to do the thing
    console.log(document.activeElement)
    if(fields.includes(document.activeElement.tagName)){
      let myField = document.activeElement;
      let startPos = myField.selectionStart;
      let endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
      myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)
            + window.location.href
            + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
      }
   }
}
// register the handler
document.addEventListener('keyup', doc_keyUp, false);
```

demo https://js.do/6by3/insert-link-at-cursor

Comment: I dont get what you meant by `as a bookmarklet`. Did you mean a browser addon?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet . Alternatively, how do I load this script so it is always available from ctrl+g in Firefox and Chrome?